# $ionicSlideBoxDelegate not populating dynamic slides

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I was having a look at a project on github for a onsen and angular weather app that I wanted to use in ionic. I am trying to change it a bit though. The main Idea is to have an ionic slide box that displays the users geolocated weather for the day then have the rest of the slides be pre entered cities around the country. I have gotten the geolocation working but I am having trouble adding additional cities. My service:

```
.factory('$weather', function($q, $http) {
    var API_ROOT = 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/';

    this.byJHB = function(coords) {
      var deferred = $q.defer();
      var long = '28.043631';
      var lat = '-26.202271';

      $http.jsonp(API_ROOT + '/weather?callback=JSON_CALLBACK&lat=' + lat + '&lon=' + long).then(
        function(response) {
          var statusCode = parseInt(response.data.cod);

          if (statusCode === 200) {
            deferred.resolve(response.data);
            console.log(response.data);
          }
          else {
            deferred.reject(response.data.message);
          }
        },
        function(error) {
          deferred.reject(error);
        }
      );
      return deferred.promise;
    };

    this.byLocation = function(coords) {
      var deferred = $q.defer();

      $http.jsonp(API_ROOT + '/weather?callback=JSON_CALLBACK&lat=' + coords.latitude + '&lon=' + coords.longitude).then(
        function(response) {
          var statusCode = parseInt(response.data.cod);

          if (statusCode === 200) {
            deferred.resolve(response.data);
            console.log(response.data);
          }
          else {
            deferred.reject(response.data.message);
          }
        },
        function(error) {
          deferred.reject(error);
        }
      );
      return deferred.promise;
    };

    return this;
  });
```

and my controller:

```
.controller('WeatherController', function($scope, $window, $geolocation, $weather, $interval, $ionicSlideBoxDelegate) {



    // Load saved cities from Local Storage.
    $scope.places = angular.fromJson($window.localStorage.getItem('places') || '[]');

    $scope.updateGeo = function() {
      $geolocation.get().then(
        function(position) {
          $weather.byLocation(position.coords).then(
            function(weather) {
              $scope.localWeather = weather;
              $ionicSlideBoxDelegate.update();
            }
          );
        }
      );
    };

    $scope.updateLocalWeather = function(coords) {

      $weather.byJHB().then(
        function(weather) {
          $scope.byJHB = weather;
          $ionicSlideBoxDelegate.update();
          $scope.places.push(place);
          $window.localStorage.setItem('places', angular.toJson($scope.places));

          setImmediate(function() {
            $ionicSlideBoxDelegate.update();
            $ionicSlideBoxDelegate.currentIndex.setItem($scope.places.length + 1);
          });
        }

      );
};



$scope.updateWeather = function() {
      $scope.updateGeo();
$scope.updateGeo();
    $interval($scope.updateWeather, 300000);
})
```

this is getting the users geolocation and displaying weather data and creating additional slides but the additional slides are not receiving any data.

anyone have any experience with this?